# Erratic OAuth 1.0 Signature Mismatch Errors

Tags: rest-api, oauth

Question for anyone who might be using OAuth 1.0 to access the REST API (via [the official OAuth 1.0 repo](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1)).

Small preface to say that I've researched this and seen multiple other questions that are similar, but not exactly applicable to my situation. I've tried various suggested fixes from multiple sources, searches, and StackExchange and seem to be no closer to a solution.

I'm running into a strange issue where I'm getting sporadic signature mismatch errors. About half the time, my callouts work perfectly (whether from my C# app or Postman), and the other half gets hit with a signature mismatch. I've tried a number of things to fix or at least diagnose the issue, none of which work, and all of which seem to be more geared towards issues where OAuth signature errors are consistent every time.

It occurs using the OAuth endpoints (like oauth1/request) but also with other endpoints throughout the API.

```
{
"code": "json_oauth1_signature_mismatch",
"message": "OAuth signature does not match",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
```

I'm on the latest stable version of Wordpress, but this issue has persisted over a number of releases.

I'm relatively new to the Wordpress REST API and to OAuth in general, so I'm unsure if there are server-side logs I can check to dig into the errors more deeply, but from what I can see, my signatures are being generated correctly as the system works intermittently, regardless of whether I'm in my app or using Postman's signature generation scheme.

My app's authentication is planned to be based on this API, as well as a number of other callouts at various points to populate data, request access to data, etc. Nailing down a smooth callout process is going to be important to ensure a smooth user experience. Not to mention keeping me sane during development.

Any ideas what would cause these erratic errors when nothing in my code is changing in between executions?

Comment: This is a fundamental problem with OAuth1, the spec doesn't define how to handle structured data clearly enough, as a result insignificant differences in different JSON implementations can cause this, as can issues such as data equivalence. My recommendation? Move to OAuth2 which is easier to implement and doesn't have this problem. Otherwise I'm afraid there is no easy fix for this. ( This is also the advice from the people who wrote the OAuth1 adaptor for the REST API, who also wrote the OAuth2 plugin )